# request code==400,trying to login into webservice

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm trying to create login feature in my app.Try to login for vid.me service,here the API(lonk for reques what I need to use) https://docs.vid.me/#api-Auth-Create
but when I did it,I create breakpoint to my app and have badrequest,code==400.
What I did wrong and what I need to do,to fix this?
**Code for debugger:**

```
rawResponse = {Response@830024013168} "Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=400, message=Bad Request, url=https://api.vid.me/auth/create}"
 body = {OkHttpCall$NoContentResponseBody@830023386408} 
 cacheControl = null
 cacheResponse = null
 request = {Request@830024545504} "Request{method=POST, url=https://api.vid.me/auth/create, tag=Request{method=POST, url=https://api.vid.me/auth/create, tag=null}}"
 handshake = {Handshake@830025387808} 
 headers = {Headers@830024520568} "Content-Type: application/json\nDate: Mon, 25 Apr 2016 12:59:49 GMT\nServer: nginx\nSet-Cookie: rid=5b6d76d16a2e4b64b8e1389422b37319; expires=Sat, 17-May-2031 01:48:34 GMT; Max-Age=475159725; path=/; domain=vid.me\nSet-Cookie: srid=frACyTReTbefXzqSuGQKkg-IggcXQ-KPkrv6l5cHG2qVwYlXc1tmaDhOs; expires=Sat, 17-May-2031 01:48:34 GMT; Max-Age=475159725; path=/; domain=vid.me\nX-Request-Time: 21\nX-Vidme-Authorization-Okay: false\nX-Vidme-Server-Id: d547f3205895e99e1b50ac97a00e7a74\nContent-Length: 92\nConnection: keep-alive\nOkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1461571136194\nOkHttp-Received-Millis: 1461571136469\n"
 message = "Bad Request"
 networkResponse = {Response@830023182616} "Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=400, message=Bad Request, url=https://api.vid.me/auth/create}"
 priorResponse = null
 protocol = {Protocol@830023796600} "http/1.1"
 code = 400
```

**myFragment:**

```
public class FeedFragment extends Fragment {
    EditText username;
    EditText password;
    Button btnLogin;

    public List<SignInResult> signInResult;
    String username_value,password_value;
    public static final String ROOT_URL = "https://api.vid.me/";

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_feed, container, false);
        username = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.user_name_field);
        password = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.password_field);
        btnLogin = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_login);
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Authorize();
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }

    public void Authorize() {
        Retrofit retrofitAdapter = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(ROOT_URL)
                .build();
        final VideoApi videoApi = retrofitAdapter.create(VideoApi.class);

         username_value = username.getText().toString();
         password_value = password.getText().toString();

        Call<SignInResults> call = videoApi.insertUser(username_value,password_value);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<SignInResults>() {


            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<SignInResults> call, Response<SignInResults> response) {
                SignInResults results = response.body();
                String usermame_result = results.signInResult.getCode();
                Log.d("Feed",usermame_result);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<SignInResults> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
}
}
```

**API interface for Fragment:**

```
public interface VideoApi {

    @GET("/videos/featured")
    Call<Videos> getFeaturedVideo();

    @GET("/videos/new")
    Call<Videos> getNewVideo();

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/auth/create")
   Call<SignInResults>insertUser(@Field("username") String username,
                           @Field("password") String password
                           );
}
```

SignInResult class:

```
public class SignInResult {
    public String getAuthorization() {
        return authorization;
    }

    public void setAuthorization(String authorization) {
        this.authorization = authorization;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    @SerializedName("authorization")
    @Expose
    private String authorization;
    @SerializedName("code")
    @Expose
    private String code;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @SerializedName("username")
    @Expose
    private String username;

    public String getUser_id() {
        return user_id;
    }

    public void setUser_id(String user_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }

    @SerializedName("user_id")
    @Expose
    private String user_id;
}
```

SignInResults class:

```
public class SignInResults {
public SignInResult signInResult;

    public List<SignInResult> getSignInResults() {
        return signInResults;
    }

    List<SignInResult> signInResults;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me that you are not setting the authorization header to your key + secret. An indicator for this would also be this response header: `X-Vidme-Authorization-Okay: false`.

I'm not familiar with the framework you are using, so I can't give you actual code, but you would need to set the HTTP request header `Authorization` to the value `basic XXX` where `XXX` is your key + a colon + your secret, base64-encoded.

So, if your key/ID was `foo` and your secret was `bar` (`foo:bar` base64-encoded is `Zm9vOmJhcg==`), you would need to send `Authorization: basic Zm9vOmJhcg==`.